# Discord.py Random Variabel Input / Ouput

Tags: python, variables, random, discord, discord.py

I would like to expand my Discord Bot with a new randomizer function.
I always want to enter the values/variables manually, for example:

`Input: !random text1 text2 text3  Output: The result is "text2"`

I need the whole thing in Discord.py (Python) and without slash (/) commands.
I tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def r(ctx, str, name1: str, name2):
    list = [str(name1), str(name2)];
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0xc81f9f,
        title="Rating",
        description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {random.choice(list)} is your rating"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manully doing `name1` , `name2` you could use `*args` to grab arguments,

```
@bot.command()
async def r(ctx, *args):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0xc81f9f,
        title="Rating",
        description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {random.choice(args)} is your rating"
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! How can i give a Output from my Input?
Titel Rating:

In Pool was: 
name1
name2
name3

The winner is {random.choice(args)}

Comment: You can do something like ```f"Input: {args} Output: {random.choice(args)}"```

Comment: Yeah this sounds good, but how can i format this? 
The normal Output ist now like this: ('test1', 'test2')
I want like this test1 \r\n test2 ,....

Comment: args is a tuple so u can do ```f"args[0] \r \n args[1] \r \n args[2]"```